# InfluxDB in Single Node Embedded IoT Applications

Tags: hardware

According to the Documentation for **InfluxDB v1.4**,

> InfluxDB should be run on locally attached SSDs. Any other storage configuration will have lower performance characteristics and may not be able to recover from even small interruptions in normal processing.

Using an SSD with an IoT node seems quite unlikely and also not very cost efficient. I have a Development board from [PhyTec](https://phytec.eu) and I am planning to use a Memory (microSD) Card.

Will this affect performance of my application in anyway? The application has *sampling rate* for **1Hz** and **10Hz** from 3-5 sources, which I do not think is a very high requirement in terms of application.

(Each source is connected to a couple of sensors and the collected values are sent to the IoT Node for acquisition and then further sent to a cloud for processing.)

Comment: Domoticz for Raspberry Pi comes with an InfluxDB instance, which obviously runs on a MicroSD card.I don't see lag or other when interrogating through the UI...

Comment: Just try and see. However, without further information, it looks to me that you may not even need an InfluxDB instance. What operations are you performing on that DB? if it is just about buffering data and relaying it to a cloud, I think you don't need any InfluxDB (or any real DB for that matter).

Comment: I am planning to use a Single Board Computer (not a Pi) which a wired Ethernet Network. The nodes send data to the SBC via the network. The complete setup is on a moving vehicle. I will need a TSDB since each node has an RTC. I will query information from the DB on timely basis and send data to the cloud via GSM module.